# Storyboard throws errors but it runs fine

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7, xcode7.3

I'm working on a project where my architecture is divided by targets (i.e. one target for views, one for view-model and one for model).

When I add a new UI dependency with IBDesignable elements (both via dependency manager or manually) my XCode shows the following errors:
[image]

However, I'm able to run my project perfectly fine and all custom libraries load fine too. I've tried deleting my projects derivedData to no avail. This is most likely an XCode bug, but is there a way to fix it and make the errors disappear?

Comment: Have your tried cleaning xcode by doing ⇧⌘K? That mostly solves xcode bugs

Comment: Yes, I've tried cleaning and rebuilding multiple times, I tried cleaning after erasing derivedData too and the errors won't disappear.

Comment: Have you also tried deleting the app on the simulator and then run it again?

Comment: I tried doing that too, but the errors in xcode persists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing this "Reactive Cocoa" library? Apparently, XCode is not able to load this library. I'm not sure if you're really using it for any purpose, but it's a shot.

Comment: I don't think the problem is due to ReactiveCocoa, as I have it as a dependency and all calls to it work just fine. Plus ReactiveCocoa is merely a back-end library, with no effect whatsoever in storyboard. This is what makes me believe this is indeed an XCode bug.